# read() buffer has invalid data (pointer issue?)

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers, io

I have the problem that the **data** array in the following function has some crappy value (looks to me like some memory location):

```
int
GPIO::GetValue() {
    char data[1];

    if (read(_valuefd, data, 1) < 0) {
        perror("Error on reading value fd");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("int GPIO::GetValue() %s\n", data);

    if (strcmp(data, "1") == 0) {
        return GPIO_VALUE_ON;
    }
    if (strcmp(data, "0") == 0) {
        return GPIO_VALUE_OFF;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

[Full Source](https://github.com/bodokaiser/node-native-io/blob/master/src/gpio.cc#L93)

Result of **printf**:

```
int GPIO::GetValue() 0cx$??ݾ??˶8@l
```

I have no idea what is going wrong on this. I extracted the same code in some simple program where it works fine. There is also some other function **GPIO::GetDirection** which does the same and also works fine. I guess there is some memory, pointer, allocation issue.

What is going wrong?

Bodo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting right result I think. Just null terminate the string `data`.

```
char data[2];
data[1] = '\0';
```

Actually, you don't need to declare an array. Just `char data;` is enough.
then you may need below changes:

```
char data;
if (read(_valuefd, &data, 1) < 0) {
        perror("Error on reading value fd");
        return -1;
    }

printf("int GPIO::GetValue() %c\n", data);

if (data == '1') {
    return GPIO_VALUE_ON;
}
else if (data == '0') {
    return GPIO_VALUE_OFF;
}
else {
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I get format ‘%c’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char*’

Comment: ??! In my example, argument 2 has type `char` and it will work fine with `%c`. I just illustrated how we could implement the same functionality with `data` as `char`, but not a `char*`.

Answer (score 1):

'data' array is 1 byte long. If you want to print it as a string it has to be terminated with a '\0'.
Or, try using %c instead of %s.

Answer (score 1):

`printf("int GPIO::GetValue() %s\n", data);` You try to display a char*.
But since you array hava a size of 1, printf don't know when to stop reading because he can't find a '\0'.

`printf("int GPIO::GetValue() %c\n", data[0]);` if you stay with an array of size 1

And your strcmp can fail, try strncmp with a size of 1